# Input type "Text" to have a blurred text, which dissappears onFocus?

Tags: javascript, html

Some websites have forms with input type="text". And inside these textboxes there is a blurred text, which says for example: "Enter your name here".
And then onClick or OnFocus or whatever, the text dissappears and you can type into the textbox.

Like the title of posting a question here at stackoverflow, same thing.

How is this done easiest way? Would prefer if there was not too much js involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not blurred text, it's called a "watermark."  You can create the same effect by using inline onfocus() and onblur() statements on your input.

For example:

```
<input type="text" 
       class="watermark"
       value="Enter your name" 
       onfocus="if ( this.value == this.defaultValue || this.value == '' ) { this.value = ''; this.className = 'regular';}" 
       onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = this.defaultValue; this.className='watermark';}" />
```

Then in your CSS file, you define classes for both `.watermark` and `.regular`.  This way the text will be semi-transparent when displayed as a watermark and become completely opaque when the user types some information:

```
input.watermark {color:#ddd;}
input.regular {color:#000;}
```

Comment: I'd change this up to use `this.defaultValue` in place of the repeated hard coding of `'Enter your name'`

Comment: What happens when you submit the form without focus on this input?  What happens if JavaScript isn't enabled?  There's a more usable, semantically better solution here.

Comment: I use this solution *only* with forms that require validation.  Even if validation isn't required, you can easily filter POSTed information to strip out any default values you've placed in the form ... unless you run into a case where someone's name really is "Enter your name" you shouldn't have a problem.  But what is your solution?  If it's a better solution, I'd love to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

That is done with an overlay. The text is not actually inside the input, but in a span above it. It is set to disappear when the user clicks.

Comment: There are a few different techniques. Placing an element above the `<input/>` is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with some of these simple add/remove label solutions posted, as their may be 1) usability issues due to the reliance on JavaScript and 2) you might have a bunch of submissions to your form that have "enter your name here" as the value.

[Here's a good overview](http://www.viget.com/inspire/a-better-jquery-in-field-label-plugin/) of the potential concerns and an offered solution.  In fact, this solution is more like the SO "Ask Question" page, which uses a span overlay as opposed to showing/hiding text.

To implement this particular solution (there are others), you would download the script [here](http://github.com/davist11/In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin/raw/master/src/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js), put it on your server, then include the following code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function(){ $("label").inFieldLabels(); });</script>
```

Comment: That is a really good option, but it does rely heavily on jQuery.  The question author asked for a solution without too much JS involved.  While the jQuery solution *is* a better option (and I think I'll be using it from now on), I don't feel that it satisfies that JS-light requirement.  All things considered, though, still +1.

Comment: But the "complete" version of your script (one that correctly filters the case where the input isn't focused) requires either 1) more JS to clear input on form submit or 2) server side validation.  And you still have the usability/accessibility issues.  I guess my point is that there isn't a "good JS light version" of this :).

Comment: Plus the question says "How is this done easiest way? Would prefer if there was not too much js involved."  I would think including two js files (jQuery, label script) and adding one line to initialize said script all in the same place would be easier than 1) adding JS to all inputs, 2) adding CSS for watermark styling and 3) adding PHP for validation.

Comment: In principle I agree with you.  I was working under the assumption that integrating jQuery would be too much JS than "Would prefer if there was not too much js involved" would allow.  That's why I opted for the onfocus/onblur system (particularly since onfocus was referenced in the answer).  In the end, I think your solution is more elegant and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the text blurred (I suppose it's theoretically possible to do gaussian blur with a canvas but I've never seen it done).

However, it is very common to set the color of the input to be a shade of light gray ("color: #ccc", for example) and have the input contain some placeholder text. Then, onfocus, you remove the css color and set the value of the input to "".

Having the text dissapear onclick is not a good idea because people will likely select the input with tab.

ex:

```
<input type="text" id="awesome" style="color: #ccc" value="Type your name here."/>

<script>
    (function(){
        var placeholder = true;
        var awesome = document.getElementById('awesome');
        var old_event = null;
        if (awesome.onfocus) {
            old_event = awesome.onfocus;
        }
        awesome.onfocus = function(){
            if (placeholder) {
                this.value = '';
                this.style.color = 'inherit';
                placeholder = false;
            }
            if (old_event) {
                old_event.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    })();
</script>
```